# Read data from IndexedDB saved by another domain

Tags: javascript

I can see an object saved in the IndexedDB by another domain `'https://previews.customer.envatousercontent.com'` in Application tab of Chrome Dev Tools.
I want to read data from it using a javascript code but it shows there are no databases.
The image shows the `localforage` database with a store named `keyvaluepairs` and the object of interest `{"best_Virus_Killer":41}`

[image]

The code I use to retrieve databases lists from the indexedDB is as follows

```
const promise = indexedDB.databases()
promise.then(databases => {
  console.log(databases)
})
```

It currently returns an empty array `[]`, although if I create a database myself it returns that specific database.

My personal thought is that since the database is saved by an external domain so I don't have access to it. But why does it still show up on the Chrome Dev Tools then.

Comment: @ikhvjs The way I am using the database here is also exactly from the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory/databases

Answer (score 1):

Your personal thought is correct. You cannot access data belonging to another site in Javascript. That would make IndexedDB totally insecure and therefore useless.

Of course in Dev Tools you can still see the databases of all sites you've visited. That data belongs to you, the user of the browser.

Comment: Dev Tools allows us to edit, delete and create values as well for the data stored by other websites, isn't that a breach on privacy? if its not then why can't we access the same data with Javascript?

Comment: Because only people with physical access to your computer can access your browser's Dev Tools.

Of course anyone with physical access can open your browsing history, go to sites you are logged into, change passwords, etc. To prevent this, you can set a password (or fingerprint, face scan or whatever) to prevent other people using your device. 

You don't see the difference between that and someone accessing all your data via Javascript while you visit any random site?

Comment: I understand now @funkizer. I just wish there was a way to verify a chrome user programmatically and get access to all the private objects

Comment: That would still open a hellhole of security issues because people who don't know much about computers, tend to just click "OK" when they're asked for permissions :D

I don't know your use case, but if you own both the sites, then you just need to find some other way to store user data that's common to both sites. Ie. maybe a third site which acts as an Auth Provider for 2 different sites.